# have you talked/ did you

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

When I ask a question "did you" it refers always to a specific moment I have in mind and "have you" refers to something up to now.

Like:

> Have you talked to him?

This question is asked if we want to know if the person has already talked to him. And a "yet" could be add at the end "have you talked to him yet".

Whereas, did you call him, is asked when we know the moment:

> "did you call him when you were in France"

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, you understand it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, yes your understanding is correct.

In certain situations, they may be used interchangeably as well:
"Have you called him yet?" and "Did you call him yet?" both could be used for the same situation, although it does heavily depend on the context.

Comment: _Did you call him yet?_ is more idiomatic in American English than in British.